# Does this attach a click even to an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript

I need to add a click event to an anchor for Google Analytics event tracking. I have the main event tracking code in the head section. I've also done this in the head section:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("btn_2_3a4z711fbd39d2fc9634f0yt66b45ht9").addEventListener("click", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Webinar', 'Register', 'webinar-july-15']);");
}
</script>
```

When I inspect the anchor tag, I don't see the event is there.  I'm going off of this example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_addeventlistener.  The event doesn't show up in the example either when I inspect it.

I don't see the event coming through in GA. I tried modifying the code to this for testing but I don't see the alert:

```
.addEventListener("click", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Webinar', 'Register', 'webinar-july-15']);alert('popup');");
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're expecting to see an `onclick` in the `a` element, you won't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Yep, you're passing a string as second argument to `addEventListener` when it should be a function.

Replace

```
document.getElementById("btn_2_3a4z711fbd39d2fc9634f0yt66b45ht9").addEventListener("click", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Webinar', 'Register', 'webinar-july-15']);");
```

by

```
document.getElementById("btn_2_3a4z711fbd39d2fc9634f0yt66b45ht9").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Webinar', 'Register', 'webinar-july-15']);
});
```

Comment: Still nothing in GA.  I also added this to the function but don't see the popup: alert('popup');.  Shouldn't the popup appear?

Comment: @4thSpace If there actually is an element with `id="btn_2_3a4z711fbd39d2fc9634f0yt66b45ht9"` and you click it, then yes, it should. I assume you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: There was - I had an extra period before addEventListener.  That is fixed it.  Still nothing in GA but that is a separate issue now.  Thanks!

Comment: Good news - the GA event is showing up.  Just a little lag.